# Is there any way I can swing my ultra greatsword faster?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I have an ultra greatsword named Greatsword. I have enough stamina to do few swings, but it takes too much time to swing the sword or to recover from the swing animation, leaving me vulnerable to attacks.

Is there any way to increase the swing speed/recover ratio for ultra greatswords?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, there is no way to increase swing speed. It was thought that raising Adaptability increased swing speed but this theory has been thoroughly dis-proven.

**NOTE:** expending your Stamina through attacking actually puts it into a **negative** value, increasing the recovery time.

A few tips to help you with your stamina management:

- The lower your equip % the faster your stamina recovers
- Try raising your Endurance to get more stamina to begin with
- Eating Green Grass will increase your stamina regen along with the Cloranthy Ring but they   do not stack
- The Cloranthy Ring does however stack with this [shield](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/shield-of-the-insolent)

It is also possible to change your attack direction mid-swing with greatswords/ultra-greatsword with the Left-stick

Comment: Please reword "Eating Green Grass will increase your stamina regen along with the Cloranthy Ring" as this gives the idea that Green Blossom stacks with the Cloranthy Ring - when in fact it does not. See: http://www.reddit.com/r/DarkSouls2/comments/20qtr0/psa_green_blossom_does_not_stack_with_cloranthy/

Comment: @brain56 Thanks for that, I've made some changes to improve the answer

Answer (score 2):

Don't listen to them!

Power stance a Lion's greataxe, a bandits greataxe, or a gyrm greataxe (i recommend lion's) with your greatsword and you will have a long-sword moveset. In other words, you will be swinging massive sword and axe around like there wooden sticks. Have fun!

Comment: This is one to try out.

Comment: What? You can't power stance different weapon types as far as I am aware

Comment: This is the **real** answer

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to increase swing speed for weapons. Each weapon type has its strengths and weaknesses, ultra greatswords in particular revolve around a high risk, high reward playstyle. The safest way to play using an ultra greatsword is to simply watch your enemies and only attack at a moment of weakness, this minimizes your chances of being hit during your comparatively large recovery window.

Don't try to get multiple hits as you aren't using a fast weapon like a curved sword. Ultra greatswords are better suited for a one-shot hit-and-run tactic.

Comment: More like hit-and-hope-you-have-enough-stamina-to-run